# Composer install history re-written error

Tags: php, git, symfony, composer-php

When I try and run composer install I am seeing the following error for my project:

```
Installing symfony/yaml (dev-master 8bae579)
Downloading
Failed to download symfony/yaml from dist: Could not authenticate against github.com
Now trying to download from source
- Installing symfony/yaml (dev-master 8bae579)
Cloning 8bae579c7afa252c055855f071c751eb75dcf6c4
8bae579c7afa252c055855f071c751eb75dcf6c4 is gone (history was rewritten?)
```

When I clone the repo manually to a separate directory and found that I could not do:

```
git checkout 8bae579c7afa252c055855f071c751eb75dcf6c4
```

It does not exist! So okay that makes some sense,

**HOWEVER**

The commit can be found still on github.com though here:

https://github.com/symfony/yaml/commit/8bae579c7afa252c055855f071c751eb75dcf6c4

Also github caches the zip of the commit so you can still download the zip here:

https://api.github.com/repos/symfony/yaml/zipball/0047c8366744a16de7516622c5b7355336afae96

**With that in mind why does composer still complain its missing?**

The relevant section of my composer.lock file is below for reference:

```
    {
        "name": "symfony/yaml",
        "version": "dev-master",
        "source": {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "https://github.com/symfony/yaml.git",
            "reference": "0047c8366744a16de7516622c5b7355336afae96"
        },
        "dist": {
            "type": "zip",
            "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/symfony/yaml/zipball/0047c8366744a16de7516622c5b7355336afae96",
            "reference": "0047c8366744a16de7516622c5b7355336afae96",
            "shasum": ""
        },
        "require": {
            "php": ">=5.5.9"
        },
        "type": "library",
        "extra": {
            "branch-alias": {
                "dev-master": "3.0-dev"
            }
        },
        "autoload": {
            "psr-4": {
                "Symfony\\Component\\Yaml\\": ""
            },
            "exclude-from-classmap": [
                "/Tests/"
            ]
        },
        "notification-url": "https://packagist.org/downloads/",
        "license": [
            "MIT"
        ],
        "authors": [
            {
                "name": "Fabien Potencier",
                "email": "fabien@symfony.com"
            },
            {
                "name": "Symfony Community",
                "homepage": "https://symfony.com/contributors"
            }
        ],
        "description": "Symfony Yaml Component",
        "homepage": "https://symfony.com",
        "time": "2015-12-05 11:13:35"
    },
```

Comment: Did you found solution for that? I have similar problem.